# Identifying the pattern between two numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a variable number, let's call it X, and a constant number, 2500. Now these 2 numbers undergo a set of operations along with other constant numbers, and the result is Y.

Is it possible to find out what are the set of operations (along with the other constant numbers), if I have the following data-

When X is 752, Y is 243,258,038. 
When X is 749, Y is 235,326,285. 
When X is 725, Y is 181,252,890. 
When X is 704, Y is 152,231,843.

Please note, you have to use the number 2500 in each of these cases. You can also use any other constant numbers etc. Also decimals can be approximated. When I say a "set of operations", I mean something simple like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, square root, powers, logs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the `X/Y` graph shows a rather **linear** dependency:

[image]

Comment: thank you, can you tell me which website you used to plot that?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just Microsoft Excel 2010